# How to align my checkboxes separate lines?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I want to align my checkboxes vertically. I mean every option in one line.
I googled it they suggested `vertical-align: middle` but it just changes the label’s position. I want every checkbox in separate lines.
my code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Dr277/g9mc762o/2/

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap by chance?

Comment: No, I don't think so :) I'm really a newbie programmer so actually, I don't know what it is yet :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.
It's great that you add link to a fiddle but you [MUST](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) add the relevant code here also.

As for your question, quick way to solve it is to wrap `label`s with element (`form`?) and style this element as flexbox (you can even delete you existing style):

```css
form {display: flex; flex-flow: column; /* remove this if you want it horizontal   */ }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
          <p>Which superpower would you like to have? 
          <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span></p>
          <form>
          
          <label>
            <input 
              name="superpower"
              type="checkbox"
              value="mind-read"
              class="input-checkbox"
            >Mind Reading
          </label>
          <label>
            <input 
              name="superpower"
              type="checkbox"
              value="invisibility"
              class="input-checkbox"
            >Invisibility
          </label>
          <label>
            <input 
              name="superpower"
              type="checkbox"
              value="teleportation"
              class="input-checkbox"
            >Teleportation
          </label>
          <label>
            <input 
              name="superpower"
              type="checkbox"
              value="Flying"
              class="input-checkbox"
            >Flying
          </label>
          <label>
            <input 
              name="superpower"
              type="checkbox"
              value="have-superpower"
              class="input-checkbox"
            >I have already a superpower
          </label>
          </form>
        </div>
```